# How to add tricky 1-to-1 : M-to-M relations for a dataframe in a new column while grouping data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the below sample data frame

```py
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': {0: 'ahmed',
  1: 'ahmed',
  2: 'mohamed',
  3: 'mohamed',
  4: 'hassan',
  5: 'ali',
  6: 'nice',
  7: 'bad'},
 'Location': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'B', 4: 'C', 5: 'C', 6: 'D', 7: 'D'},
 'Prof': {0: 'doc',
  1: 'doc',
  2: 'eng',
  3: 'doc',
  4: 'eng',
  5: 'eng',
  6: 'doc',
  7: 'eng'}})

In [2]: df
Out[2]:
      Name Location Prof
0    ahmed        A  doc
1    ahmed        A  doc
2  mohamed        B  eng
3  mohamed        B  doc
4   hassan        C  eng
5      ali        C  eng
6     nice        D  doc
7      bad        D  eng
```

I would like to add a new column `Relations` which will contain 1-to-1, 1-to-M, M-to-1 or M-to-M relation between profession and both **Name and Location combination**

I want this

```py
In [3]: df
Out[3]:
      Name Location      Prof relation
0    ahmed        A       doc   1_to_1
1  mohamed        B  eng, doc   1_to_M
2   hassan        C       eng   M_to_1
3      ali        C       eng   M_to_1
4     nice        D       doc   M_to_M
5      bad        D       eng   M_to_M
```

beside the `Relations` column, I only want unique values in `['Prof']`;

`df.groupby(['Name', 'Location'])['Prof'].agg(','.join)`

Using the above line of code resulted in `doc,doc` for the first record, which is something I don't want and I can't remove duplicates before as I have many other columns in the original data that makes both 1st rows not duplicate.

Comment: See if you require any further clarification from the answers below.  If no more question,  let us know any of the answers best fit for your needs by accepting the answer you choose.  Please also consider upvoting answer(s) helpful to you (including answer that you accept).  Thanks!

Comment: Any update ?  Just let us know if any clarification required. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1: You can set the `relation` for `Location` as follows:**

Get the unique counts of `Name` and `Prof` for each `Location` by [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`nunique()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html).

Set up `relation` using [`np.select()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)

```
# Get the unique counts of `Name` and `Prof` for each `Location`
df_count = df.groupby('Location', as_index=False)[['Name', 'Prof']].nunique()

# Set up `relation` using `np.select()`
cond_list = [(df_count['Name'] == 1) & (df_count['Prof'] == 1),
             (df_count['Name'] == 1) & (df_count['Prof'] >= 2),
             (df_count['Name'] >= 2) & (df_count['Prof'] == 1),
             (df_count['Name'] >= 2) & (df_count['Prof'] >= 2)
            ]

choice_list = ['1_to_1',
               '1_to_M',
               'M_to_1',
               'M_to_M'
              ]

df_count['relation'] = np.select(cond_list, choice_list)
```

**Step 2: Set the `Prof` as follows:**

We use [`.unique()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) to get the unique values of `Prof` for `join`

`sort=False` in `.groupby()` to keep original sequence.

```
df_prof = (df.groupby(['Name', 'Location'], as_index=False, sort=False)['Prof']
             .agg(lambda x: ', '.join(x.unique())))
```

**Step 3: Merge them together**

```
df_final = df_prof.merge(df_count[['Location', 'relation']], on='Location')
```

---

**Results:**

**df_count**

```
print(df_count)

  Location  Name  Prof relation
0        A     1     1   1_to_1
1        B     1     2   1_to_M
2        C     2     1   M_to_1
3        D     2     2   M_to_M
```

**df_prof**

```
print(df_prof)

      Name Location      Prof
0    ahmed        A       doc
1  mohamed        B  eng, doc
2   hassan        C       eng
3      ali        C       eng
4     nice        D       doc
5      bad        D       eng
```

**df_final**

```
print(df_final)

      Name Location      Prof relation
0    ahmed        A       doc   1_to_1
1  mohamed        B  eng, doc   1_to_M
2   hassan        C       eng   M_to_1
3      ali        C       eng   M_to_1
4     nice        D       doc   M_to_M
5      bad        D       eng   M_to_M
```